# Trying to access model from another model returns null

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have the following two model classes:

```
class CarRequest extends Model
{
    public function model()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\CarModel', 'model_id');
    }

}

class CarModel extends Model
{
    public function brand()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\CarBrand', 'brand_id');
    }
}

class CarBrand extends Model
{
    public function models()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\CarModel');
    }
}
```

Car request has car model and car model has car brand.

When I try to access the brand as the following:

```
$request->model->brand
```

It returns null, however

```
$request->model
```

returns the car model normally.
Also, accessing the brand from the model directly without the car request works fine as well.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: you can try `$request->model->brand()->get()`

Comment: Returned empty array @lighter

Comment: Could you verify that model actually has a brand stored in the database?

Comment: It has yes, because it works if i try to access it without the $request, i.e. if I access it directly then get the brand.

Answer (score 0):

Your models are all good.

```
$request->model
```

This works because you are using the object as is. However, if you wish to access the object's properties you have to add the parenthesis.

Perhaps try:

`$request->model()->brand`

This allows you to access the brand property in the collection model.

Comment: This returns 
Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo::$brand